# Changing color of {{ form_help('from.name) }} (Symfony 5.2)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig, symfony-forms, symfony5

I have a simple contact form. Within the form I would like to change the color of the help text

In FormType I added i. e. the name field:

```
$builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, ['help' => 'Pflichtfeld'])
```

In Twig I have this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        {{ form_label(ContactForm.name)}}
        {{ form_widget(ContactForm.name) }}
        {{ form_help(ContactForm.name, {'help_attr': {'class':'text-danger'}}) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Sadly the class is just added to the existing class when rendering and therefore is ignored:

```
<small id="contact_name_help" class="text-danger form-text text-muted">Pflichtfeld</small>
```

What do I need to do that the class defined in 'help_attr' ist overwriting the existing classes and is not just added?

Is it because I use 'bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig' as a form_theme in my twig.yaml?

Help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is because you use form theme.

You can search for 'bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig' in vendors and actually see the code.

```
{%- set help_attr = help_attr|merge({class: (help_attr.class|default('') ~ ' form-text text-muted')|trim}) -%}
```

This line adds class 'text-muted' no matter what for block 'form_help'.

You could [create your own form theme](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#creating-your-own-form-theme), extend 'bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig' and remove 'text-muted'.

```
{% extends 'bootstrap_4_form_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block form_help -%}
    {%- if help is not empty -%}
        {%- set help_attr = help_attr|merge({class: (help_attr.class|default('') ~ ' form-text')|trim}) -%}
        <small id="{{ id }}_help"{% with { attr: help_attr } %}{{ block('attributes') }}{% endwith %}>
            {%- if translation_domain is same as(false) -%}
                {%- if help_html is same as(false) -%}
                    {{- help -}}
                {%- else -%}
                    {{- help|raw -}}
                {%- endif -%}
            {%- else -%}
                {%- if help_html is same as(false) -%}
                    {{- help|trans(help_translation_parameters, translation_domain) -}}
                {%- else -%}
                    {{- help|trans(help_translation_parameters, translation_domain)|raw -}}
                {%- endif -%}
            {%- endif -%}
        </small>
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endblock form_help %}
```

Also you can remove 'text-muted' conditionally.

```
{%- set help_attr_class = help_attr.class|default('') -%}
{%- set help_attr = help_attr|merge({ 
    class: help_attr_class ~ ' form-text' ~ ('text-' not in help_attr_class ? ' text-muted')|trim 
}) -%}
```

Comment: thank you very much. I just have a lot to learn. I created my own template for it and it worked. Have to dive deeper in the link you provided and also in the link for {%- which I never saw before :)

Comment: Maybe you can help me with the conditonally removal. If I add the lines, I get the error `Unclosed "{".` and it shows the second line you posted. I can't find the problem. For me all tags are closed. I compared letter by letter ...